# How to get - LAST INSERTED Record using LinQ filter?

Tags: linq-to-entities

I have a table, It uses Guid for storing Id for each newly inserted record.

Based on other table Id, it can store more than one record(s) for the same id of other table.

I am using Linq GetQuerable Methods. Which gets all the List of records for the id I have passed.

when I select a particular record from the GetQuerable Lsit based on some filters, how can I get Last inserted record which satifies the condition? As my filter will give me more than one record and I want the Lastly inserted record.  Rather than giving me random record.

At the moment I am not having a field DateTimeRecordInserted.

Thank you

Comment: Can't you change your table and replace Guid by regular identity column?

Comment: I cannot do that as this Guid is Linked in other queries..

Answer (score 0):

[Assuming you are using SQL SERVER]

The GUID is not usefull for sorting, so you have to add either the DateTimeRecordInserted or add a field of type INT and make this an Identity column. This will auto increment and the highest value is the most recent insertion.

Additional benefit is that this field can also be used for a clustered index because I think a Guid is not very usefull - perhaps some other experts can comment on that.